# ObservableCollection always gets only first item in it for each created TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, datacontext

Can someone point on my mistake pleas.
When I add Tabs each tab duplicates data in textboxes that was added in first created tab. ObservableCollection only gets first item in it for each Tab.

I have MainView with TabControl for wich I add Tabs programmatically and set content for them through button_click

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ToolBar Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Foreground="AliceBlue" FontWeight="Normal" Click="Button_Click" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Fixed Miriam Transparent">Menu
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu >
                    <MenuItem Header="Add Invoice" Click="AddInvoice_Click"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Invoices List" Click="InvoicesList_Click"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
        <ToolBar.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF173ADE" Offset="0.431" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0B1D6F" Offset="0.646" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ToolBar.Background>
    </ToolBar>
    <DockPanel Margin="2,46,0,0" Name="dockPanel1" Width="Auto">
    <Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabCon"
        >
            </TabControl>
        </Grid >
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Through button_click I add Tabs, setting content for them and Datacontext for controls

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MVM mvm = new MVM();
    MVM2 mvm2 = new MVM2();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }


    private void AddInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mvm2.Invoice_Items.Add(new VM2());
        mvm.Itemz.Add(new VM());
        var tabItem = new TabItem();
        TabView tv = new TabView();
        tabItem.Content = tv;
        string s = string.Format("Tab");
        mvm.Itemz.Add(new VM(s));
        xmx.Itemz.Add(new VM());
        tv.dataGrid1.DataContext = mvm2;
        tv.listBox1.DataContext = mvm;
            tabCon.Items.Add(tabItem);
            if (tabCon.SelectedIndex == null)
            {
                tabCon.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            tabCon.SelectedIndex++;

    }

}
```

}

This is view for Tabs

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.TabView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Test"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="300" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="300" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" 
              Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="55,115,55,0" Name="dataGrid1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" CanUserResizeRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Invoice_Items}"
              IsReadOnly="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserAddRows="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Item_Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Itemz}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" Focusable="True" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="768" MinHeight="446" Opacity="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush />
        </ListBox.BorderBrush>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:DataGrrr></views:DataGrrr>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush />
        </ListBox.Background>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                        Value="False" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                        Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="Transparent" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                        Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                        Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="Transparent" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>


</Grid>
```

```
public partial class TabView : UserControl
{
    MVM xmx = new MVM();
    MVM2 mvm = new MVM2();
    public TabView()
    {

        dataGrid1 = new DataGrid();
        InitializeComponent();
        //mvm.Invoice_Items.Add(new VM2());
        //xmx.Itemz.Add(new VM());
        //listBox1.DataContext = xmx;
        //dataGrid1.DataContext = mvm;

    }

}
```

And this is view for `ListBox`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.DataGrrr"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="456" d:DesignWidth="887">
<Grid Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="768" MinHeight="446" Focusable="True" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="43" Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="45" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="45" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="170" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Supplier, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Height="27" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="11,6,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="141" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding}" />
    <Label Content="Supplier" Height="27" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="21,6,0,0" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" Background="White" MinWidth="133" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

One of the ObservableCollection

```
class MVM : BVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<VM> items = new ObservableCollection<VM>();

    public ObservableCollection<VM> Itemz
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Itemz");
        }
    }
```

}

And the model

```
    class VM: BVM
{
    private string supplier;


    public VM()
    {

    }

    public string Supplier
    {
        get
        {
            return supplier;
        }

        set
        {
            if (supplier != value)
            {
                supplier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Supplier");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use list and check result, but i think problem is not in ObservableCollection,
problem is in class thet you binding to tab, it works like if you bind one object  to every new tab, like static